# Button event, event.target.dataset returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Here is the component, the first half of the if statement works fine but the second half which passes data to an event handler returns undefined.**

```
const SearchResult = (props) => {
 
  if (props.result.length === 1) {
        return(
        <div> 
          {console.log(props.result)}
          <h2>{props.result[0].name.common}</h2>
          <div><b>Capital: </b>{props.result[0].capital}</div>
          <div><b>Area: </b>{props.result[0].area}</div><br></br>
          <div><b>Languages: </b></div><br></br>
          <div>{Object.values(props.result[0].languages).map(languageValue => <li>{languageValue}</li>) }</div>
          <div>
            
          <p><img
                  src={props.result[0].flags.png}
                  alt="National Flag"
                  height="100"
                  width="150"
                  srcSet={props.result[0].flags.svg}
          />
          </p>
          </div>
          </div>
        )
  }



  else { 

          return(
          <div>
            {props.result.map((country) =><div><li key = {country.ccn3}>{country.name.common} <button  data-value={country} onClick={handleButton}> Show details </button> </li> </div>)} 
          </div>
          )

}

}
```

**The event handler of the button.**

```
const handleButton = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const { value } = e.target.dataset;
  console.log(value);
  

};
```

**console.log(value) returns undefined.**

Comment: undefined or is it object Object?

Comment: Are you sure `e.target.dataset.value` is what you're looking for?

Comment: @SudhanshuKumar Yes, Object Object. Slightly changed the code before I posted. I changed 'value2' to 'value' and it changed from undefined to Object Object. ill edit now.

Comment: @AchiPapakon I want to get the object for each country in the map, so when the button beside each country is clicked I can display more details about that particular country. I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint somewhere inside that `handleButton` function and see what's wrong. Maybe e.target doesn't get the object that you plan to.